# how to find the joint density function here?

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

let $X, Y \stackrel{}{\sim} \mathscr{N}(0,1)$ be two independant r.v's

I want to find the joint PDF of $(X,Z)$ where $Z = X^2+Y^2$

how do I proceed ?

I have tried the following : ($F$ denotes the CDF and $f$ the PDF)

$$ \begin{align}  F_{X,Z}(x,z) & = \mathbb{P}(X \leq x, Z \leq z) =  \mathbb{P}(X \leq x, Y^2 \leq z - x^2) \\ & =  \mathbb{P}(X \leq x, -\sqrt{z - x^2} \leq Y \leq \sqrt{z - x^2}) \\
& =  \mathbb{P}(X \leq x, Y \leq \sqrt{z - x^2}) + \mathbb{P}(X \leq x, -\sqrt{z - x^2} \leq Y ) \\
& = F_{X,Y}(x,\sqrt{z - x^2}) + {\color{red}{\mathbb{P}(X \leq x, -\sqrt{z - x^2} \leq Y )}}
\end{align} $$

I also know how to find $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ but I don't know how to  deal with the red term.

any help or other methods will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer to question, but you can check [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution)

Answer (score 1):

Polar coordinates help here.
\begin{align}
\Pr(X^2+Y^2 > w) & = \iint\limits_{ \left( \begin{array}{c} \text{complement of} \\ \text{disk of radius }\sqrt w \end{array}\right)} \frac 1 {2\pi} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} \, d(x,y) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(R^2>x) = \int_0^{2\pi} \underbrace{ \left( \int_{\sqrt w}^\infty \frac 1 {2\pi} e^{-r^2/2} r \, dr \right) }_{\text{No $\theta$ appears here.}} \,\,d\theta \\[10pt]
& = \int_{\sqrt w}^\infty e^{-r^2/2} r\, dr = \int_{w/2}^\infty e^{-u} \, du = e^{-w/2} \text{ for } w\ge 0.
\end{align}
Thus $X^2+Y^2$ has an exponential distribution with expected value $2.$