# is this method fine to find the joint PDF?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have already sought for help in a previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2724130/how-to-find-the-joint-density-function-here) concerning the problem :

let $X, Y \stackrel{}{\sim} \mathscr{N}(0,1)$ be two independent random variables.

find the joint PDF of $(U,Z) = (X,X^2+Y^2)$

so I proceeded as follows :

\begin{align}
&\int_{\mathbb{R^2}}f_X(v)f_Y(w)dvdw = 1 = \int_{\mathbb{R^2}}f_{U,Z}(m,n)dmdn  \\
& \int_{\mathbb{R^2}}f_X(v)f_Y(w)dvdw  = \int_{\mathbb{R \times \mathbb{R_{+}}}}2f_X(v)f_X(w)dvdw =\int_{\mathbb{R \times \mathbb{R_{+}}}}\frac1{\pi}\exp[-{{(v^2+w^2)} \over {2}}]dvdw = J\\
\end{align}

using the the change of variable $n = v,\; m = v^2+w^2$ we have :

\begin{align}
J & = \int_{\mathbb{R \times [n^2,+\infty[}}\frac1{2\pi\sqrt{m-n^2}}\exp[-{{m} \over {2}}]dmdn \\ 
& =  \int_{\mathbb{R^2}}\frac1{2\pi\sqrt{m-n^2}}\exp[-{{m} \over {2}}] \cdot \chi _{[n^2,+\infty[}(m) dmdn \\
\end{align}

can I say that $f_{U,Z}(u,z) = \frac1{2\pi\sqrt{z-u^2}}\exp[-{{z} \over {2}}] \cdot \chi _{[u^2,+\infty[}(z) $ ?

Comment: No, using/showing that $J=1$ cannot yield the result. Why not use instead the Jacobian formula for changes of variables? This is the entirely standard approach...

Comment: @Did I tried using the jacobian approach but the $Y$ had a $ \text{+\-} $ sign I thought using an integral I could get rid of that by using that $f_Y$ is even

Comment: Please show in details how you applied the Jacobian method.

Comment: @Did Well, $|J(x,y)|^{-1} = \frac1{2\sqrt{z-u^2}}$ 

and $f_{U,Z}(u,z) = f_{X,Y}(X(u,z),Y(u,z))\cdot \frac1{2\sqrt{z-u^2}}$

but the mapping $(x,y) \mapsto (x,x^2+y^2)$ doesn't have a nice inverse. it depends on the sign of $Y$

Comment: This is not what I call showing the details of how one applied the Jacobian method... Anyway, using your notations, $(U,Z)=g(X,Y)$ hence $$f_{U,Z}(u,z)=\sum_{(x,y)}\frac1{\left|\mathrm{Jac}(x,y)\right|}f_{X,Y}(x,y)$$ where the sum is over every $(x,y)$ such that $$g(x,y)=(u,z)$$ In your case, for every $z>u^2$ the sum has two terms, each equal to $$\frac1{2\sqrt{z-u^2}}\frac1{2\pi}e^{-z/2}$$ hence $$f_{U,Z}(u,z)=\frac1{\sqrt{z-u^2}}\frac1{2\pi}e^{-z/2}\mathbf 1_{z>u^2}$$